# Python .loc returning a TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, pandas-loc

I'm new to using .loc , but every time I try to use it, it returns 'TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable'.

For example, I can't get this simple code (used on the pokemon API) to work:

```
print(df.loc(df('Attack') > 175))


TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Please can someone help, its really bugging me why it's not working ?!?

Comment: `df('Attack')` should be `df['Attack']`.

Comment: `print(df.loc[df['Attack'] > 175])`

Comment: Thanks :D @corralien

Comment: Thanks @Barmar!

Answer (score 2):

Indexing (both `iloc` and accessing column `Attack`) should be done with square bracket, not round bracket (as they are not functions)

For instance

```
 df.loc[df['Attack'] > 175]
```

With `df('Attack')`, you are trying to call `df` object, which of course is not not a function and hence not callable